# customize helm action when no match selection

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

Emacs version 24.4.1.

I search a lot material, and find the someone have tried below:
http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/02/02/helm-actions-when-there-is-no-match/

and wikemacs:
http://wikemacs.org/wiki/How_to_write_helm_extensions

but could not work for me.

I want to customize helm interface. use selection candidate where there is one, and use user input when there is none. like `helm-find-files`.